# How can I get the list of people I am following on Instagram without using the API?

Tags: python, list, instagram

I can download all photos of a single profile using a python script called instaRaider. I want to download all the photos of the people I am following by looping through the list of those people and running the instaRaider script for each of them.

Can I get the list of people I am following without using the API endpoint provided by Instagram?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the API?

Comment: It asks for the app I am building to be submitted and accepted. I am not building an app. I am just trying to get all the media of my followers and my following. Without that the API just returns error 200 with an empty list called 'data'.

Comment: could be done with selenium/scrapy?